# How to join 2 sql command

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

How can I do this with this 2 sql statements?

```
select trade_date, count(*) from tableone group by trade_date order by trade_date;
select trade_date, count(*) from tabletwo group by trade_date order by trade_date;
```

I want to join these two statements to create a result like follow:

```
trade_date, tableone.count, tabletwo.count
```

grouped by trade_date.

Can someone Help?

Answer (score 0):

Simple JOIN

```
SELECT coalesce(a.trade_date,b.trade_date) as trdate, a.cnt , b.cnt FROM
(SELECT trade_date, count(*) AS cnt FROM tableone GROUP BY trade_date) A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT trade_date, count(*) AS cnt FROM tabletwo GROUP BY trade_date) B
ON a.trade_date = b.trade_date
ORDER BY trdate;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great.  Now i have to join 34 of those select statements. urgh!!!!...

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with your statement is when the list of trade dates in the two tables are not the same.  In that case, you will want a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(agg1.trade_date, agg2.trade_date) as trade_date,
       coalesce(cnt1, 0) as cnt1,
       coalesce(cnt2, 0) as cnt2
from (select trade_date, count(*) as cnt1
      from tableone
      group by trade_date
     ) agg1 full outer join
     (select trade_date, count(*) as cnt2
      from tabletwo
      group by trade_date
     ) agg2
     on agg1.trade_date = agg2.trade_date
order by coalesce(agg1.trade_date, agg2.trade_date);
```

EDIT:

With three tables, the structure of the code is very similar:

```
select coalesce(agg1.trade_date, agg2.trade_date, agg3.trade_date) as trade_date,
       coalesce(cnt1, 0) as cnt1,
       coalesce(cnt2, 0) as cnt2,
       coalesce(cnt3, 0) as cnt3
from (select trade_date, count(*) as cnt1
      from tableone
      group by trade_date
     ) agg1 full outer join
     (select trade_date, count(*) as cnt2
      from tabletwo
      group by trade_date
     ) agg2
     on agg1.trade_date = agg2.trade_date full outer join
     (select trade_date, count(*) as cnt3
      from tablethree
      group by trade_date
     ) agg3
     on agg3.trade_date = coalesce(agg1.trade_date, agg2.trade_date)
order by coalesce(agg1.trade_date, agg2.trade_date, agg3.trade_date);
```

Comment: sql failed giving me an error: ORA-00904: "T2"."TRADE_DATE": invalid identifier.  I know tabletwo has trade_date column so does tableone.

Comment: @user3221575 . .  I don't know why I switched the table aliases from `agg1` and `agg2` to `t1` and `t2`.  But the code is fixed.

Comment: this worked great too.  How would this look like if i had to add a third table "tablethree"?.  thanks you so much.